# Absolute zero search engine referrals - Am i banned or something?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines

It's been about 3 months that i have developed my new website. I've never had such a problem, but in these 3 months i had less than 16 visitors from google.

I used every method i knew to preserve the quality and standards, such as:

- Using schema.org markups
- Caching the pages
- Using fresh contents
- Mobile friendly design
- Using proper keywords and H* tags
- Sitemap
- Posting in social networks
- And so many more items which you guys certainly know better than me.

I even designed the theme myself from scratch so i know there is no malicious code or anything in it.

I have no idea why this is happening to me. The only sources i get visitors are **facebook** and **twitter**.

There is no error or any warning in my google webmasters console.

Is it possible that i'm banned or restricted from gaining search engine referrals?

Comment: Not banned or restricted. Just new! Make sure your content is ***your*** original and valuable content, that you have at least 300 pages, and that you have a link profile that makes a search engine stand up and notice. Even then it can take 6 months to soak into a search engine and begin performing well. It all depends mostly on the content, how unique it is, the quality of the content, how competitive it is, and the number and quality of the back links. 3 months is not enough time generally.

Comment: @closetnoc thank you, but you know what i'm wondering about? I have another website, with the same design and content type that gets more than 100 daily visitors from google (only 1 month older). I can't put these 2 conflicts together in my mind.

Comment: It could be the topic space. It could be this site in question is in a more competitive space. If that is the case, then you may have an up-hill battle for a while at least. There are literally a thousand and one reasons why a site does not perform the way you expect. Being 3 months old, I would not be worried at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Analyze where those 16 users came from.  If they are legitimate SEO traffic you will want to build more article, posts, etc to continue to feed that niche.  You will need to ensure analytics is setup and analyze the data coming in.  You will also want to make sure you are focusing on internal linking and backlinks to your website from reputable sources.  There are many thin websites that have ranked very well with great authoritative links.

**Somethings to consider:**

- Focus on the load speed
- Install an SSL Certificate If you can.
- Ensure the IP address of your website is unique or not saturated with other websites.
- Ensure your sitemaps are setup correctly so search engines know about the pages that exists on your site.
- Ensure your anchor text is unique and connects to keywords of pages you want to rank for.
- Make sure your robots.txt file is setup correctly.  Since you built the theme yourself you maybe missing some of the core files that search engines bots needs to index your site properly.

If you have gotten traffic ultimately you will want to duplicate the process.  Data is your best friend.  The more you dive into your analytics data the better you will get at spotting trends and attacking your seo from there.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I agree with number 1 to 3, which i haven't done yet. Although number 4-6 are done properly. The 16 visitors were from google, about 1 every 10 days, or maybe 2 in a single day. Each referred by a very long search query. I also noticed that all my categories, tags, etc... are indexed by google, and not all of my real posts! (about 20% of them indexed)

Comment: If it has been 3 months and your posts have not been indexed? there is def a technical issue you are running into on your website.  Are you using a plugin for sitemaps? I am assuming you are using Wordpress?

Comment: Yes, I'm using google sitemaps on WordPress. I checked the sitemaps (those which aren't indexed) and none of them are broken.

Comment: I would suggest using the "yoast seo plugin" for wordpress and enable the sitemaps in that plugin.  There have been known issues with that google sitemaps plugin.  The yoast seo plugin will also allow you to index your images as well.  This maybe where you issue is.  You may also not have google seo sitemaps settings setup correctly in wordpress.

Comment: Also have you checked to make sure your meta descriptions and title tags are unique?  I have also seen this happen when pages have duplicate content in category listing pages.  You want to make sure your post listing pages have a read more tag and not the whole post that links to the full article.

Comment: Thanks. I don't use Yoast because it will index my full size image (which i don't want to). I noticed that i have 4 duplicate meta tags in google console and fixed it. Each tag is like `MySite | Title`, and i try to set title and description as unique as possible. Also since my website is about images and doesn't have much text, i don't have a `Read More` tag.